# FBconnect is not working in android :(

Tags: android, facebook, fbconnect

I have follow the step mentioned in http://code.google.com/p/fbconnect-android/wiki/Setup

But it is giving error on project build

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/codecarpet/fbconnect/FBLoginDialog$FBRequestDelegateImpl;
[2010-08-07 16:46:13 - fbconnect-sample]    at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
[2010-08-07 16:46:13 - fbconnect-sample]    at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:143)
[2010-08-07 16:46:13 - fbconnect-sample]    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:299)
[2010-08-07 16:46:13 - fbconnect-sample]    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:276)
[2010-08-07 16:46:13 - fbconnect-sample]    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$100(Main.java:56)
[2010-08-07 16:46:13 - fbconnect-sample]    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:228)
[2010-08-07 16:46:13 - fbconnect-sample]    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
[2010-08-07 16:46:13 - fbconnect-sample]    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:130)
[2010-08-07 16:46:13 - fbconnect-sample]    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:108)
[2010-08-07 16:46:13 - fbconnect-sample]    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:245)
[2010-08-07 16:46:13 - fbconnect-sample]    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:183)
[2010-08-07 16:46:13 - fbconnect-sample]    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:139)
[2010-08-07 16:46:13 - fbconnect-sample]    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor16.invoke(Unknown Source)
[2010-08-07 16:46:13 - fbconnect-sample]    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[2010-08-07 16:46:13 - fbconnect-sample]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
[2010-08-07 16:46:13 - fbconnect-sample]    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.sdk.DexWrapper.run(Unknown Source)
[2010-08-07 16:46:13 - fbconnect-sample]    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.ApkBuilder.executeDx(Unknown Source)
[2010-08-07 16:46:13 - fbconnect-sample]    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.ApkBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
[2010-08-07 16:46:13 - fbconnect-sample]    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:627)
[2010-08-07 16:46:13 - fbconnect-sample]    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
[2010-08-07 16:46:13 - fbconnect-sample]    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:170)
[2010-08-07 16:46:13 - fbconnect-sample]    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:201)
[2010-08-07 16:46:13 - fbconnect-sample]    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:253)
[2010-08-07 16:46:13 - fbconnect-sample]    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
[2010-08-07 16:46:13 - fbconnect-sample]    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:256)
[2010-08-07 16:46:13 - fbconnect-sample]    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:309)
[2010-08-07 16:46:13 - fbconnect-sample]    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:341)
[2010-08-07 16:46:13 - fbconnect-sample]    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:140)
[2010-08-07 16:46:13 - fbconnect-sample]    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:238)
[2010-08-07 16:46:13 - fbconnect-sample]    at     org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
[2010-08-07 16:46:13 - fbconnect-sample] 40 errors; aborting
[2010-08-07 16:46:13 - fbconnect-sample] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

Comment: did you correctly read this.. " 'api' project is not an Android project, it's not supposed to produce apk file runnable on device, it's just library. It is regular Java project, but because it uses classes from Android SDK, there is one needed step in Eclipse configuration to make it compilable."..???

Comment: Yes API will not have apk file bt the sample-facebook, which is android project that is not creating .apk file, It build fines but at the time of run it is giving above errors

Comment: What IDE are you using ? Eclipse sometimes gives these issues which go away once you remove the library reference and add it again.

Comment: Which sample app are you trying?

Comment: Sheikh he might be talking about Sample App comes inside fbconnect-android.zip package which i also have downloaded from [link](http://code.google.com/p/fbconnect-android/downloads/list).. I went through all steps given here [link](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/android/845/) on this site, but after including that jar file into sample app it shows above error..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused because the API project is java project and not an android project.

Do the following to solve this:
1. create a new Android project
2. mark it a as library (project properties->android->Is Library)
3. copy the API src contents into your new project
4. in the sample project, add the new project as library (project properties->android->add)
5. remove from the sample project references to the old API project (project properties->java build path)

Notes:
1. if you get a blank page when you run the sample project, its because you need to set kApiKey and kApiSecret parameters in MainActivity
2. if try to view main.xml in "Graphical Layout" and you get java.lang.NullPointerException, go to FBLoginButton.java-> private Drawable buttonImage() and change the first line from

```
if (_session.isConnected())
```

to

```
if (_session!=null && _session.isConnected())
```